# Send variables from Symfony2 PHP file to js file

Tags: javascript, symfony, highcharts

I'm really new to JavaScript and I could't fine some tutorials about this. If there are ones, please tell me to read them.

What I want to do is pass variables from my PHP controller to a .js file - I want to populate Highcharts variables.

I know that I can send response, but I need to load a template, too.

This is the template:

```
...

{% block body %}

 <h1>Months</h1>

 // This is the Chart:    
 <div id="container" style="width:100%; height:400px;"></div>

    {%block javascript%}
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

        <script src="{{ asset('bundles/acmebudgettracker/js/month.js') }}"></script>
    {%endblock%}

{% endblock %}
```

The .js file called `month.js`

```
      $(function () { 
$('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
        type: 'bar'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Budget for months'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Spent', 'Saved']
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Fruit eaten'
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Jane',
        data: [1, 0, 4]
    }, {
        name: 'John',
        data: [5, 7, 3]
    }]
});
```

});​

And the controller:

```
public function monthsAction()
{
    $this->setUser();
    $month_repository = $this->setRepository('Month');
    $month = new Month();
    $form = $this->createForm(new MonthType(), $month);

    $all_months = $month_repository->findByUser($this->user); 

    return $this->render('AcmeBudgetTrackerBundle:Months:months.html.twig', array(
        'all_months' => $all_months,
        'form' => $form->createView()
    ));
}
```

What I want to do is to give variables from the controller to month.js and still be able to show the template. Any ideas or tutorials how to achieve this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Quick & "dirty" answer : set the variable in your TWIG file using  balises, and use those vars in your JS file.

```
<script>
    var foo = {{ bar }};
</script>
```

Answer (score 14):

You can generate javascript as twig template:

<kbd>**MonthsController.php**</kbd>

```
public function scriptAction()
{
    // some logic
    return $this->render('AcmeDemoBundle:Months:script.js.twig', array(
        'user_months' => $user_months
    ));
}
```

<kbd>**routing.yml**</kbd>

```
javascript_route:
  path:     /generated-scripts/month.{_format}
  defaults: { _controller: AcmeDemoBundle:Article:script, _format: js }
  requirements:
      _format:  js|json
```

<kbd>**script.js.twig**</kbd>

```
$(function () {
    var options = {
        chart: {
            type: 'bar'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Budget for months'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Spent', 'Saved']
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Fruit eaten'
            }
        },
        series: []
    };

    {% for user in user_months %}
    options.series.push({ name: '{{ user.name }}', data: [{{ user.months|join(',') }}] };);
    {% endfor %}

    $('#container').highcharts(options);
});​
```

Comment: That's a nice way of doing it, thanks for sharing. :)
But it creates new issues : how can you reuse your javascript in other part of your app ? One new controller each time ?
You need two controllers for one page, which is kinda weird.
It depends on what you need to do I guess!

Comment: Why he need 2 controllers for one page? He just create new method in existing controller…

Comment: Two actions*, I'm sorry! :)